# Long-term health consequences of consistently repeated food comas?

Tags: nutrition, diet

A [food coma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Postprandial_somnolence) is usually when a person eats too much and they get very tired due to a high influx of insulin in their blood that tries to balance out the massive rush of glucose from food.

[There was some research looking at nap latency](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/9284488), but I was more interested in long-term effects like development of chronic diseases or effect on the body.

Comment: Are you essentially asking what happens if you keep eating too much?

Comment: No, that would be "Long term health consequences of eating too much". I wonder if brain activity changes, or sleep patterns are affected. Would brain fog be long term? Would it make a person more susceptible to food comas over time? I've discovered a connection with type-2 diabetes too...